Connecting Google Sheets and Contacts
I want to write code for an Apps Script connecting Google Contacts and Sheet.
Background: Let's say there are two people, A and B. When a new contact is created/added either in A's or B's Google contacts, does it automatically get added as a new row in ONE COMMON GOOGLE SHEET?
This is the piece of code I used. However it is pulling new contacts only from the user A and not User B. Although it is running for both users and getting other contacts too, but new ones for user B are not updating.
// Function to retrieve contacts from People API and append to the common Google Sheet
function exportContactsToSharedSheet() {
  // Replace with the ID of the shared Google Sheet where contacts will be stored
  var sharedSheetId = 'PUT_SHARED_SHEET_ID_HERE'; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sharedSheetId).getActiveSheet();

  // Identify the user adding the contacts
  var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Call People API to get connections (i.e., contacts)
  var people = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
    pageSize: 1000
  }).connections;

  if (people && people.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      var person = people[i];
      var name = person.names && person.names.length > 0 ? person.names[0].displayName : 'No Name';
      var email = person.emailAddresses && person.emailAddresses.length > 0 ? person.emailAddresses[0].value : 'No Email';
      var phone = person.phoneNumbers && person.phoneNumbers.length > 0 ? person.phoneNumbers[0].value : 'No Phone';

      // Append contact details to the shared sheet
      sheet.appendRow([name, email, phone, currentUser]);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No contacts found.');
  }
}

// Set up time-based triggers for automation (e.g., every hour)
function setupTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportContactsToSharedSheet')
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(1)  // Set interval as per your needs
    .create();
}


Who ran setupTriggers?

Getting the new Contact from User A and User B
The reason why the script isn't working is because User B will also need to run the setupTriggers() function. As per Restrictions:

Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them.

I also modified the script to add a condition inside the for loop to allow both users to add new contacts from their respective ends.
There's also a discrepancy where duplicate values were being added to the spreadsheet. To improve this, I implemented a function that prevents users from adding existing contacts. Only the latest entry will be added to the spreadsheet.
Script used for exportLatestContactsToSharedSheet() & getExistingContacts()
function exportLatestContactsToSharedSheet() {
  var sharedSheetId = 'PUT_SHARED_SHEET_ID_HERE';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sharedSheetId).getActiveSheet();
  var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log('Current User: ' + currentUser);
  var existingContacts = getExistingContacts(sheet);
  Logger.log('Existing Contacts: ' + JSON.stringify(existingContacts));


  var people = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
    pageSize: 1000
  }).connections;

  if (people && people.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Number of Contacts Found: ' + people.length);
    var newContacts = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      var person = people[i];
      var name = person.names && person.names.length > 0 ? person.names[0].displayName : 'No Name';
      var email = person.emailAddresses && person.emailAddresses.length > 0 ? person.emailAddresses[0].value : 'No Email';
      var phone = person.phoneNumbers && person.phoneNumbers.length > 0 ? person.phoneNumbers[0].value : 'No Phone';

      if (!existingContacts[email]) {

        sheet.appendRow([name, email, phone, currentUser]);
        newContacts++;
        Logger.log('Added Contact: ' + name + ', ' + email);
      } else {
        Logger.log('Existing Contact: ' + email);
      }
    }

    if (newContacts === 0) {
      Logger.log('No new contacts to add.');
    } else {
      Logger.log(newContacts + ' new contact(s) added.');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No contacts found.');
  }
}


function getExistingContacts(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var existingContacts = {};

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var email = data[i][1];
    if (email) {
      existingContacts[email] = true;
    }
  }
  return existingContacts;
}

function setupTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportLatestContactsToSharedSheet')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}

Sample Output
Validation for existing Data

Spreadsheet

Note:

Make sure that the People API is added in the Services.
Make sure the user has Editor access.
You can still add the setupTriggers() or set manually in Installable Triggers.

Reference

getDataRange()

SetupTrigger()


